# Do the sum weekly in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table with some date and some values and I want to do the sum by week.

I use this query to do that

```
SELECT SUM(nb_like) AS nb_like , CONCAT(date, '-', date + INTERVAL 6 DAY) AS week
FROM fb_stats
GROUP BY WEEK(date)
ORDER BY WEEK(date)
```

the problem is: The sum is not correct (if I do the sum from 2016-01-16 to 2016-01-22 [![enter image description here][1]][1])and I don't know why the start day is not correct

Comment: Kindly provide sample data as text instead of an image.

Comment: In general it's smart to group by the thing you're selecting

Comment: Are you sure you want to group by `WEEK` only? That would mix all years, e.g. week 4 would countain week 2016/4, 2015/4, 2014/4, etc.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I use YEARWEEK the sum still not correct

Comment: With `YEARWEEEK` the sum should be correct, but the dates are probably not. See my answer on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are grouping by `WEEK(date)`, so as to get one result row per week. The expression

```
CONCAT(date, '-', date + INTERVAL 6 DAY)
```

however is not an aggregate (like `SUM`, `MAX` or the like). So the `date` in this expression is just one of the dates found in the records of the week arbitrarily picked.

What you want instead is the week's first day. In order to do so make sure first that you use an appropriate mode for the `WEEK` function (or rather `YEARWEEK` in order not to mix the years) to ensure there exists that day in every week selected, e.g:

```
YEARWEEK(date, 2)
```

which gets you weeks starting with Sunday. Mode 7 would get you week starting with Monday instead. Read up un this here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week.

Then use this method to get the Sunday from the week:

```
STR_TO_DATE('<yearweek> Sunday', '%X%V %W');
```

Replace <yearweek> with the real yearweek. (And replace 'Sunday' with 'Monday' if you decide for mode 7.)

The complete query:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(nb_like) AS nb_like, 
  CONCAT
  (
    STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEARWEEK(date, 2), ' Sunday'), '%X%V %W'),
    '-',
    STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEARWEEK(date, 2), ' Sunday'), '%X%V %W') + INTERVAL 6 DAY
  ) AS week
FROM fb_stats
GROUP BY YEARWEEK(date, 2)
ORDER BY YEARWEEK(date, 2);
```

Comment: Thanks !! this is I wanted :)

Comment: if I want to filter between two date for example ( 2016-12-01 AND 2016-12-31) I need to use a sub query ?

Comment: Sounds like a simple where clause to me: `where date between '2016-12-01' and '2016-12-31'`.

Comment: I tried it , but I think I have to change the query for example if I want the result for the period '2016-12-01 / 2016-12-31' , the output I want is:
2016-12-01 - 2016-12-08 > 2500
2016-12-09 - 2016-12-16 > 8799
2016-12-17 - 2016-12-24 > 1558
...

Comment: Yes. You would want a where clause to restrict the data, but you also don't want pre-defined weeks anymore, but merely seven-day ranges starting at the given start date. Use math for this. The distance in days from start date divided by 7 (integer division) will give you the group into which a date belongs.